# Python. Нужно реализовать ввод пользователем своих оценок по предметам с проверкой ввода

Tags: python, исключения

Нужно реализовать ввод пользователем своих оценок по предметам с проверкой ввода, что бы в случае, если оценка меньше 2 или больше 5, программа требовала повторить ввод, но только для того предмета , на котором произошла эта самая ошибка. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
marks = {}
for subject in ('математика', 'русский', 'химия', 'биология', 'физика'):
    while True:
        try:
            mark = int(input('Введите оценку за предмет {}: '.format(subject)))
            if 2 <= mark < 6:
                marks[subject] = mark
                break
            else:
                print('Ошибка: Число должно быть не меньше 2 и не больше 5!')
        except ValueError:
            print('Ошибка: Введено не число!')
```